# Angularjs .substr is not working while i want to take first 10string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here i have some token like

```
Aa0Jf_hvsXgd9BLr4iKErA2C_jEGlMxye0hkczkYJNykyXC44_-Y6VxdlM-b5PY-ZYorTPgsgMVB1SHRjC-hLFGMQwc0Dt-cYwtOIpWtbjX1wtE2m-BYb9OHFCe3L9mMH1TzSaLeztFPH2A8gAV8DExbzNc-
```

From this Token i need the first 10  digits of this 
i had written as:

```
 var AccesToken = localStorage.getItem('loginToken');

   function abc() {
        _AccesToken = AccesToken.substr(10);
        $scope.token = _AccesToken;
        console.log($scope.token);
    }
```

but here i am getting output as "" (empty string). Please give me any hint.

Answer (score 2):

for substr you should specify two params (one option and one required). In your case it is start not length . Check [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)

```
var str = 'Aa0Jf_hvsXgd9BLr4iKErA2C_jEGlMxye0hkczkYJNykyXC44_-Y6VxdlM-b5PYZYorTPgsgMVB1SHRjC-hLFGMQwc0Dt-cYwtOIpWtbjX1wtE2mBYb9OHFCe3L9mMH1TzSaLeztFPH2A8gAV8DExbzNc-';
abc();
function abc() {
        var _AccesToken = str.substr(0, 9); // 0 is the start 9 is the number of char to extract.
        console.log(_AccesToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks a bit off for _AccesToken assignment:

```
var AccesToken = localStorage.getItem('loginToken');
var _AccesToken = null; //make sure this is declared somewhere

   function abc() {
    _AccesToken = AccesToken.substr(10);
    $scope.token = _AccesToken;
    console.log($scope.token);
    }
```